# wso2esb how can add all dependent jar file in a executable class mediator jar

Tags: wso2-esb

I have created the project using WSO2 Developer Studio. Under src/main/java I created the package com.training In that package the class UnzipFileMediator:

```
package com.training.mediators;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

//Import another jar dependent jar
import com.test.Testing;


public class UnzipFileMediator extends AbstractMediator { 

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        // TODO Implement your mediation logic here 
        System.out.println("UnzipFile Mediation entered*****");

       // Dependent JAR class

        Testing t= new Testing();
        t.sayHello();
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this project i have deployed another jar by using the following step

```
1. Right click on the project
2. Select configure build path
3. Select Java Build Path
4. Select Libraries
5.Click on Add External Jar. Then add the external jar called Hello
6. Hello Jar contain the class Testing
7. Above mentioned class import Dependent Testing class and create the `object and call the function as mentioned below.`
8.import com.test.Testing;
9. Its working fine here.
```

Now i am going to deploy it on WSO2ESB following are the step to creating the Jar file:

```
1. Right click on the project
2. Select Export
3. Select Runnable JAR File
4. Select the check box 
                Package Required libraries into generated JAR
6. JAR is created and available to deploy at WSO2ESB
```

I will deploy this jar into WSO2ESB below is the location:

```
1. <ESB_HOME>/repository/components/lib directory.
```

In the synapse configuration I call the class like this

```
<class name="samples.mediators.UnzipFileMediator"></class>
```

but when i try to call it.It generate the below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/Testing
```

This is the dependent JAR file class as i mentioned above

Please guide me what i did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put that dependent jar in lib directory. But make sure that two or more jars don't contain the same package (when it happens, class loading problems occur)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that If you can make maven OSGi bundle this would be really easy. I will explain how to do it.

**Step 1:**
Create a maven-archetype-quickstart projet.You can generate this using this command.If you already installed Maven.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Then create a package as you wish. As an example, it should be similar to this.   [image]

**Step 2:**

Then you need to modify you pom.xml similar to this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>com.training.mediators</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<groupId>4.0.0</groupId>
<name>com.training.mediators</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
        <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3-wso2v11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.training.*
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        *,*;resolution:=optional
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Fragment-Host>synapse-core</Fragment-Host>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>wso2-maven2-repository</id>
        <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>apache-Incubating-repo</id>
        <name>Maven Incubating Repository</name>
        <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating-repository</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>apache-maven2-repo</id>
        <name>Apache Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>wso2-nexus</id>
        <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>wso2-maven2-repository</id>
        <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>wso2-maven2-snapshot-repository</id>
        <url>http://dist.wso2.org/snapshots/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Here one important point is the export-package section you need to mention which sub packges are to export.

```
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.training.*
                    </Export-Package>
```

You don't need to import dependencies. Those things will be imported automatically.

**Step 3:**

Now it's time write your logic in your mediator class.

```
package com.training.mediators;

import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class UnzipFileMediator extends AbstractMediator {

 public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
    // TODO Implement your mediation logic here
    System.out.println("UnzipFile Mediation entered*****");

    // Dependent JAR class

    return true;
}

public String getType() {
    return null;
}

public void setTraceState(int traceState) {
    traceState = 0;
}

 public int getTraceState() {
     return 0;
 }
}
```

**Step 4:**

type `mvn clean package` in the directory where your pom.xml file is located.

Then there will be generated a folder called **target**. In that folder, there should be `*.jar` file something similar to this: `com.training.mediators-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Copy `com.training.mediators-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` to `wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/components/dropins`.

Restart ESB server.

**Step 5:**

Now you need to add an ESB configuration as you required. Here is sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<sequence name="fault">
    <makefault version="soap11">
        <code value="tns:Receiver" xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>
        <reason value="Mediation failed."/>
    </makefault>
    <send/>
</sequence>
<sequence name="main" onError="fault">
    <in>
        <class name="com.training.mediators.UnzipFileMediator"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint name="stockquote">
                <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/AdderService?wsdl"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </in>
    <out>
        <send/>
    </out>
</sequence>
```

I hope this will help :)